# Angular - ngxTranslate in ts file

Tags: angular

I need to translate text strings in a ts file using [NGX Translate](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core).

I add the translate service and try to do similar to this

```
constructor(
    translate: TranslateService
  ) {
    translate.get("hello.world").subscribe((text: string) => {
      console.log(text); // WORK BUT I NEED TO ADD THIS IN ARRAY
    });

    this.idiomasTodos = [
      { id: 1, descripcion: translate.get("spanish") }, //THIS OTHER WAY NO WORK
      { id: 2, descripcion: translate.get("basque") }, //THIS OTHER WAY NO WORK
      { id: 3, descripcion: translate.get("english") } //THIS OTHER WAY NO WORK
    ];
```

So, how can i translate any text strings directly in array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `get` method use `instant` method

```
    constructor(
        translate: TranslateService
      ) {
        this.idiomasTodos = [
          { id: 1, descripcion: translate.instant("spanish") }, 
          { id: 2, descripcion: translate.instant("basque") },
          { id: 3, descripcion: translate.instant("english") } 
        ];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to achieve that could be to translate each word directly in the view, instead of doing in the component, using `translate` pipe :

```html
<ul *ngFor="let idiomasTodo of idiomasTodos">
    <li>{{ idiomasTodo.descripcion | translate }}</li>
</ul>
```